# Best way to create multi-platform mobile games?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, multiplatform

I know there are topics on this but, I kind of just want to get a straight answer.  I am interested in creating mobile games (and I plan on putting a lot of time into them) except at this point it is only me at this point.

The point I am getting to is this: I have read everywhere online on the recommended ways to create multi-platform mobile games and I am aware of most of the sdk's and other tools like MoSync, Corona, etc...  (I am also looking for a 'as free as possible solution')

** By the SDK's I mean the 'write once play everywhere' mentality' where I would write an app that would work on most platforms**

What really is the best way to create a mobile multi-platform game?  Is it worth using one of these sdk's or in all honesty is it truly recommended to just create the game separately on each platform's native sdk (like iOS and Android and Windows Phone)?  Should I waste time trying to find a good multi-platform game sdk or should I build each separately for its platform?  What do most people/companies do who create games for the major platforms, like angry birds, temple run, etc...?  If it is recommended to maybe use a 'write once play everywhere' SDK then in all honesty, which one is the perfect solution.  (2D gaming)

Thanks everyone. Appreciate the input and help.

Comment: There aren't many solutions that support all three, mostly because it is a huge pain in the ass to support Windows along with *anything*.  Your best bet is probably Cocos-2DX (The C++ port of Cocos-2D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually been looking into this a lot over the last few weeks. There are a few options:

-Unity: free now for the base mobile product. Looks like you use the unity editor, build out your games there and then it generates code based on the platform. You have to write code for the game objects in the editor using C# or Javascript.

-Cocos2d-x: Free game engine, looks like you can write code in C++ and then port it across all the platforms since they are all capable of building C++ code.

I'm sure there are more out there but I was between those two and SpriteKit. Since I primarily do iOS I decided to go with SpriteKit (has some really cool features you can check out if you're an Apple Developer, plus great documentation and pretty straight forward). I still really like Unity but I'd also be doing all the artwork by myself and Unity seemed like it would show off poor art quality more than a 2d engine.

There are some pretty nice Unity tutorials you can check out on YouTube to get a feel for it. I think if cross platforming was my biggest concern I'd dig deeper there first and see if it was a fit.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into Unity but, is that optimal for 3D games?  Does SpriteKit also work with Android?  Out of all of them, would you recommend one over the other?  How simple is Cocos-2d to work with? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Unity is a 3D engine. That's what it does best. SpriteKit is only iOS and Mac OS. I found Cocos-2d to be a pain, they iterate it so fast that a lot of the tutorials out there are outdated. Cocosbuilder seems like it would make it Cocos2d a lot easier to use but there's only one tutorial on it and documentation is very scarce. CocosDragon is a great tutorial but it's outdated with the new build and covers only one type of game.